# Exact Number comparison

Tags: php, numbers

I need one solution for this script. I don't want to remove the first zero because I show the example code only. In case I have received zero in my random function. This is my script.

```
<?php 
$var1 = '0123456';
$var2 = '123456';
if($var1 == $var2){
    echo 'Equal';
} else{
    echo 'Not Equal';
}
?>
```

In here I get the output is `Equal` But I need `Not Equal`. I know these two values are same, But am working on OTP So it should not allow this method. How can I do this, any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `===`

```
<?php
$var1 = '0123456';
$var2 = '123456';
if($var1 === $var2){
    echo 'Equal';
} else{
    echo 'Not Equal';
}
```

---

`===` - Checks both value and datatype (Strict comparison) - When you compare with this, both are considered as strings

`==` - Checks only value (Loose comparison) - When you compare with this, `0` will be dropped for comparison as it compares like integer values.

---

Know more about the equality from another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/5447994)

Comment: Thanks For the Valuable information @Thamilan. It's Working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace it With Your Script

```
   <?php
   $var1 = '0123456';
   $var2 = '123456';
   if($var1 === $var2)
   {
    echo 'Equal';
   } 
   else
   {
    echo 'Not Equal';
   }
   ?>
```